# Changing the Background color of a MFC application

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, background, mfc-feature-pack

I am working on a very large MFC application. There are hundreds of dialogues in this application. Now, I want to change the Background color and Font size of all dialogues in MFC application. How can I do this? Whether I have to handle WM_CTLCOLOR massage for each and every dialogue or any other work around?

*Note: I can not use any library like BCGSoft, Xtreme Toolkit.*

Comment: A quick method might be is to call `CWinApp::SetDialogBkColor`. This will change the background color (and text color) of all dialogs in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Dialog class and handle WM_CTLCOLOR massage in that class, Now derive every other Dialog of your MFC application from this class.